# Adding Rows to NSTableView without waiting for method to complete

Tags: objective-c

I have a small problem. Maybe someone can help.

I have a routine that adds rows to an NSViewTable. After each addObject I issue a reloadData as I'd like the rows to show one by one as they are added, but, what I get, is a pause and then all the rows appearing altogether at once. There is a little bit of processing involved, and getting the rows to show one by one as sub-processing completes would make a nice progress indicator.

Would anyone know if there is a way to get the rows to show one by one as they get added rather than a pause and then all the rows appearing at once?

Plenty of thanks,

Comment: It depends on how you populate your table with data.  Don't make readers take a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `-reloadData` results in exactly the behaviour you're seeing: it reloads the entire table view. This is a very expensive operation and should only happen when initially loading a data set or completely replacing a data set. For incremental updates such as yours, use `-[NSTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation:]`.

I'm assuming that you're asking how to animate each row one by one. For this, you'd probably want to use `dispatch_after()` to stagger the insertion of each row by a fixed number of seconds to create the effect of each row animating in separately.

Example (assuming you're adding the objects to the end of the array):

```
// objectsToAdd is the array of objects that you're adding to the existing array
// self.objectArray is the existing array of objects
NSArray *objectsToAdd = ...
NSUInteger existingCount = self.objectArray.count;
NSUInteger addedCount = objectsToAdd.count;
[self.objectArray addObjectsFromArray:objectsToAdd]

// Delay between each row animating in
const double delayInSeconds = 0.2;
for (NSUInteger i = existingCount; i < (existingCount + addedCount); i++) {
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * i * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you indragie, your suggestion has been very helpful.

Comment: Good to hear. If this answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you marked it as correct.